# По какой причине GET запрос axios.js отдает Network Error?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, сервер, axios

Отправляю с локального компьютера с помощью `axios.js` `GET` запрос на `localhost:3000` - где располагается rails-приложение, отдающее **JSON** - и получаю ошибку **Network Error**.

Если открыть напрямую в браузере - все работает, **JSON** отдается. Думал, причина в `localhost` - загрузил на **Heroku** - вижу тот же результат. Но если отправить `GET`, например, на сервер `API` **stackoverflow** - то все окей.

Что я могу делать не так?

AXIOS:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/')
.then(function (response) {
     ap.answer = _.capitalize(response.data.answer)
     ap.img = _.capitalize(response.data.image)
})
.catch(function (error) {
    ap.answer = 'Ошибка! Не могу связаться с API. ' + error
})
```

RAILS:

```
result = {answer: name, image: image}

respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render json: result, content_type: "application/json", status: 200}
end
```

Comment: Код ошибки есть?

Answer (score 1):

Дело было в заголовках. Нужно прописать следующее в

**application_controller.rb:**

```
  after_action :set_access_control_headers

  def set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
  end
```